# Rolling on a frictionless pond

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, friction

I have a doubt about one of the questions in my textbook.

> **Q-** You are standing with your bag in your hands in the middle of a friction-less pond. How can you come out of the ice?

There is of course the obvious answer that by throwing the bag in one direction, we gain velocity in the opposite direction due to the law of conservation of momentum. And in this way we can come out of the pond easily.

**But my question is,** is coming out of the pond by first lying down on the ice, and then attempting to roll possible on a friction-less surface?

Comment: How do you gain the torque needed to roll without friction?

Comment: You don't need the bag.  Turn your head to one side and inhale, then turn your head to the other side and exhale.  Keep doing that.

Comment: @ja72 well gravity+normal makes torque easy! I bet that a lopsided shape could get spinning as fast as it wanted (by "standing up" and "falling over"), so torque isn't a problem.

Comment: There's no torque unless there's something to torque against.  On a frictionless surface the center of mass will remain unmoved unless there's an "equal and opposite" action somehow.  (One does wonder how this person remains standing.  I know I'd fall on my dorsal region almost instantly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Lying down on a surface could only serve to change the coefficient of friction, but the problem asks you to suppose that it's zero.

The general proof that you absolutely cannot do it by any motion, is the fact that with only gravity as an external force, momentum is conserved in the horizontal directions. The force of gravity and the normal force of the surface both mean you can jump up and down as much as you want, but the laws of physics tell us momentum is conserved here in horizontal plane.